# Work with double quotes and parameter adding to a query

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

Original Query which I can run positive in PgAdminIII:

```
SELECT * FROM oestrat."Themenfeld"
```

**oestrat** and **Themenfeld** are strings coming from Winform textboxes.

So my query in VS would be:

```
string qry = "SELECT * FROM @schema.\"@line\"";

NpgsqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@schema", tbSchema.Text)); // tbSchema.Text = oestrat
cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@line", l)); // string l = Themenfeld

cmd.CommandText = qry;

conn.Open();
NpgsqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (dr.Read()) <<< ERROR
{
     ....
}
```

It always catches an Exception:

```
42601: syntax error at or near "@"
```

Comment: Check what `cmd.CommandText` is equal to after this `cmd.CommandText = qry;` line

Comment: It is equal to `SELECT * FROM @schema."@line"` and yes, the raw unparamaterised works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe you can specify table names as parameters... only *values* can be specified as parameters.

Instead, either have a white-list of permitted table names, or at least a white-list of permitted *characters* within table names, apply that to your user input, and then - carefully - build the SQL dynamically.

Comment: There should be an "escape identifier" or "quote identifier" method somewhere in `conn` for properly escaping table/column/... names. No idea what it would be called in C# though.

Comment: @muistooshort: I'm not aware of one - that's rarely necessary in C# due to parameterized SQL, which is generally preferred over quoting. I'm not aware of a general convention for such a method, at least.

Comment: But identifiers aren't parameters in the same way that variables can't hold the names of other variables (without some sort of `eval` construct of course) so you're stuck with quoting and identifier quoting is database-specific (backticks for MySQL, brackets for SQL-Server, double quotes for standard SQL, ...).

Comment: @muistooshort: Yes, I'm aware that you can't use parameters for identifiers - that's basically what my answer says. But I'm saying that there isn't - as far as I'm aware - a quoting/escaping method available.

Answer (score 0):

Just parse the schema and table name into the string...

```
string qry = $"SELECT * FROM {tbSchema.Text}.{l}";
```

Obviously you will have cleansed these input values for SQL injection...

Comment: That's the exact reasoning, the parameters allow it to not require "*cleansing*" manually